# GFCI Protected Outlet Trips with GFCI Outlet Tester, but the outlet lost power

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci

I plugged my GFCI Outlet Tester into a GFCI protected Outlet. Pressing the test button, the outlet was tripped fine. But no matter how I pressed the reset button on the GFCI receptacle. The outlet showed no power. Could someone tell me why I cannot get power anymore from the outlet? Thank you.

Comment: if there a breaker tripped in your panel? or another gfci protected outlet?

Comment: What make and model is the GFCI in question? It could very well be that it "locked out" because it's broken inside

Comment: @ratchet freak my breaker is fine. I tested in the first gfci protected outlet so all downstream outlets have no power.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Eaton is the brand for GFCI receptacle. Here is link: https://tinyurl.com/yxptbw7s

Comment: Give Eaton a call. They're reachable by phone, and I've found their warranty department extremely helpful.

Comment: I also just noticed the two neutral wires (line & load) were reversed. Was this installed by mistake?

Comment: Wow, that would sure cause that! Yes, correct that before writing off the GFCI. Had nothing ever been plugged into the downline terminals??

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I thought the GFCI switch in the master bathroom was controlling the outlets in the same room. After some testings, however, I found out that the outlets were actually controlled by a GFCI switch in the guest bathroom. All the devices are working fine. Thank you all for your suggestions. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### Replace the GFCI, it's shot

Given that it's a modern GFCI that did this, it's trying to tell you "I'm broken inside and can no longer provide GFCI protection" when it's stubbornly refusing to reset.  So, it's time to replace it with a new GFCI; if you need help with that, post a new question here with photos of the inside of the junction box in question.

Comment: Never mind. I thought the GFCI switch in the master bathroom was controlling the outlets in the same room. After some testings, however, I found out that the outlets were actually controlled by a GFCI switch in the guest bathroom. All the devices are working fine.Thank you all for your suggestions. Very much appreciated.

Comment: @Louis -- post that as an answer and I'll give you a +1, glad you were able to figure it out!